# Acceptance Testing a Ember Datepicker Component with Ember CLI

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, acceptance-testing

I'm using Pikaday to create an Ember Datepicker Component within an Ember CLI project. It seems to be impossible to test user interactions within the component test. Does anyone know how to do this?

For example I'm trying to test that the Pikaday widget is displayed when the input of the component is clicked. The test looks like this:

```
import { test, moduleForComponent } from 'ember-qunit';

moduleForComponent('datepicker-input');

test('is an input tag', function() {
  equal('INPUT', this.$().prop('tagName'));
});

test('clicking the input opens the pikaday dialog', function() {
  ok($('.pika-single').hasClass('is-hidden'));
  click(this.$().find('input'));
  ok(!$('.pika-single').hasClass('is-hidden'));
});
```

The second tests fails due to `ReferenceError: click is not defined`. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, as far as I can tell my tests do the same as the example on the Ember.js website: http://emberjs.com/guides/testing/testing-components/#toc_interacting-with-components-in-the-dom

So I'm guessing the problem could be also with Ember CLI. Any help is welcome, I'm open to suggestions how to test the user interactions of an component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up starting and destroying the app by hand. In addition I also teardown the component after every test by hand. This is necessary until a few upstream changes from the QUnit addon land in Ember CLI.

You can look at the complete test file on GitHub: https://github.com/edgycircle/ember-pikaday/blob/master/tests/unit/components/pikaday-input-test.js

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the component to the DOM.

```
test('clicking the input opens the pikaday dialog', function() {
    $input = this.append();

    ok($('.pika-single').hasClass('is-hidden'));
    click('#your-input').then(function() {
        ok(!$('.pika-single').hasClass('is-hidden'));
    });
});
```

Comment: This uses the `click` method from jQuery and not the integration test helper provided by Ember.js. So not quite what I want to accomplish.

Comment: Ok fixed to use integration test helper. Note that it takes a selector, not an element.

Comment: As my question states the problem is that the `click` integration test helper is not defined.

Comment: Ember 1.7 no longer uses local test helpers. Make sure they are being injected by calling App.setupForTesting() and App.injectTestHelpers(), as Stanley said. In ember-cli, this should be done for you in tests/helpers/start-app.js

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call `App.setupForTesting`, and in older versions of ember, additionally `App.injectTestHelpers` before the tests are run.

http://emberjs.com/guides/testing/integration/#toc_setup

You also need to call `this.append` to make the component show up in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

In what version of Ember was this problem? I've tested with the auto-generated component test almost identically on how I tested on an ember App on an Ember AddOn (ember 2.4.3).

```
import { moduleForComponent, test } from 'ember-qunit';
import hbs from 'htmlbars-inline-precompile';

moduleForComponent('image-item', 'Integration | Component | image item', {
     integration: true
});

test('it renders an image with alt', function(assert) {
    this.set('src', 'image.png');
    this.set('alt', 'grandmother');

    this.render(hbs`{{image-item src=src alt=alt}}`);

    assert.equal(this.$('img').attr('src'), 'image.png');
    assert.equal(this.$('img').attr('alt'), 'grandmother');
});
```